# Update on array change

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

if I add an object to the objectListDrawArea array outside of the original class, it will be added, but my * ngFor cannot find the object. I have absolutely no idea how to solve it, should I use Observable, if so can you leave an example in the comments? Thank you

ao-bar.component.ts

```
import { AoBarService } from './ao-bar.service';
import { DrawAreaComponent } from '../../../draw-area/draw-area/draw-area.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ao-bar',
  templateUrl: './ao-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ao-bar.component.sass']
})
export class AoBarComponent implements OnInit {

  objectsList: object[] = new Array();

  showObjectsList: boolean;

  drawAreaComponent: DrawAreaComponent = new DrawAreaComponent();

  constructor(private service: AoBarService) { 
    this.service.getObject(this.objectsList);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.objectsList, ' AoBarComponent');
  }

  private onShowObjectsList() {
    this.showObjectsList = !this.showObjectsList;
  }

  public onDragEnd(event: DragEvent): void {
    console.log('drag end', event);   

    if (this.drawAreaComponent.onDragEnter) {

      for (let object of this.objectsList) {

        if (object.name == event.path[0].nextElementSibling.innerText) {

          object.settings.x = event.x;
          object.settings.y = event.y;

          this.drawAreaComponent.createObject(object);
        }
      }  
    }
  }


}
```

draw-area.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragEnd } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-draw-area',
  templateUrl: './draw-area.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./draw-area.component.sass']
})
export class DrawAreaComponent implements OnInit {

  objectsList: object[] = new Array();

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  public onDragEnter(event: DragEvent): boolean {
    console.log('drag enter', event);

    return true;
  }

  public onDragEnd(event: CdkDragEnd): void {
    console.log(event);
  }

  public createObject(objectToCreate: object): void {
    this.objectsList.push(objectToCreate);

    console.log(`Aktuelle Liste: ${this.objectsList}`);
  }
}
```

draw-area.component.html :

```
<div id="DrawAreaComponent">
  <div 
    class="example-boundary"
    (dragenter)="onDragEnter($event)"  
  >

    <div 
      id="ContainerObject" 
      *ngFor="let object of objectsList | async"
      cdkDragBoundary=".example-boundary"
      cdkDrag
      (cdkDragEnded)="onDragEnd($event)"
    >
      <img id="ImgObject" [src]="object.imgUrl">
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a change detection issue.

instead of `this.objectsList.push(objectToCreate);`

use `this.objectsList = [...this.objectsList, objectToCreate];` it will work.

read about change detection.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i will read about change detection. Unfortunately, the solution you added in the answer didn't work.

Comment: Ok I see, you dont have an observable or other stream that updates on change of the array. I think you should use ngrx store in order to handle the data in one place and handle data updates

Comment: I am a Beginner. I've been having this problem for 4 days, I'm looking at ngrx store. Thanks